# %ud, %vud what are those

Tags: c++, database, types

What is the meaning of this code written in c++?

```
PGBulkInserter pgBulkInserter(postgreSQL, HOST_TRAFFIC_SCHEMA_NAME, date,
                            flushSize, "%ud, %ud, %ud, %ud, %ud, " \
                            "%ul, %ul, %Vul, %Vud, %Vud, %Vud, %Vul, " \
                            "%Vud, %Vud, %Vud, %Vud, %Vud, %ud, %ud, " \
                            "%ud, %ud, %ud");
```

I understand that it is creating an instance of `PGBulkinserter`, but what is the meaning of `%ul, %ud %vud`, etc.? Would you explain the deeper meaning (i.e., how many parameters `PGbulkinsterter` has, etc.)?

I think they are like types `%d, %f`, etc. Does anyone knows if  `%ud` means an unsigned version of `%d` (I'm just guessing).

Edit: I'm pretty sure that `%ud` is a 32 bit unsigned decimal, which is used for time in another piece of code. Also, `"%ul, %ul, %Vul, %Vud, %Vud, %Vud, %Vul, "` is related to the type for all entries in the table. Now, the question is **what is `\`?**

Comment: If this is from [PgBulkInserter.cs](https://github.com/kppullin/Simple.Data.PostgreSql/blob/master/src/Simple.Data.PostgreSql/PgBulkInserter.cs), then it is C#, not C++.

Comment: this seems related but i know it is c++ or at least it is used in c++ code which properly works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is supposed to be an initialization (a constructor call), then it passes 5 arguments to the constructor. The last argument is a string literal. It has no C++-specific meaning. It's meaning is determined by the function. Read the function documentation to figure out what it means. It looks similar to C-style format string (`fscanf`/`fprintf`), but the actual specifiers (like `%Vud`) are not standard.

The last argument is really a single string literal split across multiple lines. C++ language concatenates consecutive string literals (i.e literals separated by whitespace) into a single literal. For example this sequence of seemingly separate literals

```
"Hel" "lo" " worl" 
"d"
```

is actually interpreted by the compiler as a single literal

```
"Hello world"
```

The `\` character at the end of the line causes the preprocessor to combine several lines of source file into a single line. For that the `\` character must be the last character on the line (as in your example). For example, this

```
in\
t\
  ma\
in(\
)
```

is equivalent to

```
int main()
```

In other words, your code sample is really equivalent to

```
PGBulkInserter pgBulkInserter(postgreSQL, HOST_TRAFFIC_SCHEMA_NAME, date, flushSize, 
  "%ud, %ud, %ud, %ud, %ud, %ul, %ul, %Vul, %Vud, %Vud, %Vud, %Vul, %Vud, %Vud, %Vud, %Vud, %Vud, %ud, %ud, %ud, %ud, %ud");
```

The author of the code apparently believed that in order to make the compiler to concatenate literals, they have to be forced into a single line first. For that they used the `\` character. However, it was completely unnecessary, since the literals would have been concatenated anyway even without the `\`.

In your specific code sample you can completely remove the `\` characters at the end of each line, and it will have absolutely no effect on the program. Sometimes people use those `\` anyway just to draw attention to he fact that the literal continues on the next line.

Comment: i dont know %Vud parts but the beginning is valid c++ code. PGBulkInsterter pgbulkins(x1,x2,....,xn) creates an instance of PGBulkInserter named pgbulkins initialized with x1, x2.... ,xn. it is not a function call.
in java it is like that: 
     MyClass myinstance = new MyClass(parameters)

Comment: How does the code look like function declaration? To me it's like a constructor call.

Comment: @tusherity: You are right. Somehow I got stuck on thinking about it as a standalone function call. I changed the answer.

Comment: the writers of the code i m trying to understand are really good. so i dont wanna say they are wrong or they write unnecessarily write that. i just noticed that maybe `\\` character is for indicating nextline in postgresql. they are going to next line and showing next line they put it